# Bootstrapping a glmer model in R and associated errors

Tags: r, glm, lme4, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following glmer model which I have run in lme4, in R:

```
    m1=glmer(Survived~Offset+(1|Trial/Chamber), family=binomial, data=surviveData)
```

Survived is a binary response, Offset is a three level factor, Trial is a 2 level factor and Chamber is a 24 level factor. There are 1721 observations in the data set. I would like to obtain 95% CIs for the parameter estimates of this model. To do this I have used the following:

```
    b_par<-bootMer(x=m1,FUN=fixef,nsim=1000, use.u = FALSE, type="parametric")

    boot.ci(b_par,type="perc",index=1)
    boot.ci(b_par,type="perc",index=2)
    boot.ci(b_par,type="perc",index=3)
```

I have searched for a worked example of boostrapping a glmer model to check that I am using the correct options, however I have not found a good example. There also does not seem to be a definitive solution for errors, of which I get quite a few that look like:

```
    In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
      Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00142642 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

So my questions are:

1. Have the options that I have specified for the bootstrap suitable for a glmer model?
2. Is there any solution for fixing errors like this yet or do we have to wait for the optimizers to be improved in the lme4 package?
3. If error messages are given, does the boot.ci only use the successful re-samples to compute the bootstrap statistics with, and ignore the ones that did not converge? If this is the cae, can I still use the confidence intervals despite the warnings?

Comment: Would profile CIs, i.e., `confint(m1)`, be an alternative for you?

Comment: @Roland I was boostrapping as the residuals for the model looked a bit off, so I wanted to get robust estimates of the CIs